# How to automatically LeftClick, RightClick and Scroll with C#

Tags: c#

How do I automatically LeftClick, RightClick and Scroll up or down on my desktop Using C#

I Want the method like so:

```
public void RightMouseClick(int x, int y) { }
public void LeftMouseClick(int x, int y) { }
public void Scroll(int x, int y, int amount) { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your beautifully written code

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int 
    dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;

    private static void Scroll(int Xposition, int Yposition, int amount)
    {
        SetCursorPos(Xposition, Yposition);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, Xposition, Yposition, amount, 0);
    }

    private static void LeftMouseClick(int Xposition, int Yposition)
    {
        SetCursorPos(Xposition, Yposition);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
    }

    private static void RightMouseClick(int Xposition, int Yposition)
    {
        SetCursorPos(Xposition, Yposition);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, Xposition, Yposition, 0, 0);
    }
```

bon apetite

Comment: Nice, Just what I wanted, I have a question though, what exactly are the values assigned to your constants, like "0x02 and 0x0008  etc." ?

Comment: @CedrocMoore they are the values for different flags that are available. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event (note that this function is written in C or C++ in the dll)